# gatsby-source-prismic V3.0.0-beta.26 in previewhas previewData linked documents as Proxy array

Tags: gatsby, preview, prismic.io

When i test the website into preview mode, i get the data, but the slices or content relationship don't have the same model. The data is of type "Proxy".

How can i get the data as in the non preview? Is there a serialzer to use?

Here is a screenshot of my console.

[image]

Another example here with my categories reference. There is a Proxy array but the document becomes a string.

[image]

It says in the documentation

> If previewData contains a document nested in staticData: Returns a new object with the nested document replaced anywhere it is referenced. Note that this only works if the nested data in staticData includes the document's ID field. This is useful for previewing documents whose data is only a smaller part of a whole page.

I do give ids to my nested document but still i get an empty response

```js
                tags {
                    tag {
                        id
                        type
                        document {
                            ... on PrismicCategorieBlog {
                                id
                                uid
                                href
                                dataString
                                data {
                                    title {
                                        text
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```